# Sort Model into Alphabetical Sections with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, alphabetical-sort

I implementing RecyclerView with Section Headers. I have implemented the Sections Headers and my `String[] names` have been filtered into their sections respectively. I am unable to filters the rest of the String[] presence, available & images. How can I sort the other Strings into their respective sections?

```
 public GroupChatFragment(){}
    String[] names;
    String[] presence;
    String[] available;
    String[] images;

    @Override
    protected void initView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super.initView(inflater);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        names = resources.getStringArray(R.array.group_names);
        presence = resources.getStringArray(R.array.users_presence);
        available = resources.getStringArray(R.array.users_available);
        images = resources.getStringArray(R.array.group_images);
    }

@Override
    protected void addDataToAdapter(SectionedRecyclerAdapter adapter) {
        for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
            ArrayList<Group> groups = getHeadersWithLetter(alphabet);
            if (groups.size() > 0) {
                adapter.addSection(new GroupChatSection(String.valueOf(alphabet), groups));
            }
        }
    }

private ArrayList<Group> getHeadersWithLetter(char letter) {
    ArrayList<Group> groupArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String contact : names) {
        if (contact.charAt(0) == letter) {
            Group group = new Group();
            group.setGroupName(contact);
            for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
                group.setAvailableUsers(available[i]);
                group.setGroupImage(images[i]);
                group.setNumUsers(presence[i]);
            }
            groupArrayList.add(group);
        }
        Collections.sort(groupArrayList, new Comparator<Group>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final Group object1, final Group object2) {
                return object1.getGroupName().compareTo(object2.getGroupName());
            }
        });
    }
    return groupArrayList;
}
```

Here is the [image: screenshot!]

Answer (score 1):

you have to use collection sort with Comparator for sorting model class, check this:

```
 Collections.sort(groupArrayList, new Comparator<Group>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Group object1, final Group object2) {
            String obj1 =object1.getGroupName()+object1.getGroupImage() + object1.getAvailableUsers() +object1.getNumUsers();
            String obj2 =object2.getGroupName()+object2.getGroupImage() + object2.getAvailableUsers() +object2.getNumUsers();
            return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
        }
    });
```

Add this lines above return statement in getHeadersWithLetter method, hope this will help you..:)

Comment: Can you please the post again? I have added the code but it doesn't filter the rest of the objects to their respective sections

Comment: you can change compareTo value Group name to Presence or Available or Image like:       


return object1.getPresence().compareTo(object2.getPresence());





return object1.getAvailable().compareTo(object2.getAvailable());




return object1.getImage().compareTo(object2.getImage());

the way which you want.

Comment: Could you post the complete code how should I get this done? Because it still hasn't worked for me

Comment: do you want filter the object like search or you want Model class object sorting ?

Comment: Model Class Object sorting

Comment: sorting can be based on Name and Presence and Available and Image ?